# open multiple files "sequence"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

My application is ASP .NET MVC; I am trying to open multiple files from a directory and store the files names in a variable (collection).  For example if I have 10 files named (M1, M2, M3 ...), I am using the following to open one file:

```
string imagefile =
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + "M1");
```

I know the number of files in that directory. Would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using MVC you can just use the `UrlHelper`: `@Url.Content("~/Content/M1")`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/"), "M*");
```

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/wz42302f.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I got the following error:  Bad array declarator: To declare a managed array the rank specifier precedes the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed size buffer field, use the fixed keyword before the field type.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of file with proper nameing then that would be so easy to make your code.

use below code

```
string[] imagefile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + "M*");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function GetFilesNames() As List(Of String)

    Dim dir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(_filesDirectory)
    Dim lstFiiles As New List(Of String)

    If dir.Exists() Then
        Dim files As FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles("*.png")
        For Each f As FileInfo In files
            lstFiiles.Add(f.Name.Substring(0, f.Name.IndexOf(".")))
        Next
    End If
    Return lstFiiles
End Function
```